# How to generate one hot encoding for DNA sequences using R or python

Tags: python, r, matrix, one-hot-encoding

I want to generate one hot coding matrix for a list of DNA sequences. I have tried to solve my problem from the following link  [How to generate one hot encoding for DNA sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263772/how-to-generate-one-hot-encoding-for-dna-sequences) but some of the solutions are given only for one single DNA sequence and not for a list of DNA sequences.

For example

```
def one_hot_encode(seq):
    mapping = dict(zip("ACGT", range(4)))    
    seq2 = [mapping[i] for i in seq]
    return np.eye(4)[seq2]

one_hot_encode("AACGT")
```

In the given above code, if I run `one_hot_encode("AACGT","GGTAC","CGTAC")` it will fail, also i want to generate matrix as output.

Currently, I am working in R and below is my DNA sequence in the r data frame(single-column file)

```
ACTTTA
TTGATG
CTTACG
GTACGT
```

Expected output

```
1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

is it possible to do this in R?

Comment: Are all the sequences guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: Yes - you can either recode the function to accept multiple arguments or a list of arguments, or you can use `lapply()`  to apply your function to each member in a list then `rbind()` the resulting list into a data frame.

Comment: @SamR Yes all sequences are in the same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

dataIn <- c(
  "ACTTTA", 
  "TTGATG", 
  "CTTACG", 
  "GTACGT"
  )

one_hot_encode <- function(baseSeq) {
 outSeq <- stringr::str_replace_all(baseSeq, c("A" = "1000",
                                  "C" = "0100",
                                  "G" = "0010",
                                  "T" = "0001"))
 outSeq <- str_extract_all(outSeq, boundary("character"))
 unlist(outSeq)
}

data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(dataIn, one_hot_encode)))
```

gives

```
 > data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(dataIn, one_hot_encode)))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24
1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
4  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
```

Some row and column names might tidy up the output, but I think this is essentially what you were after?

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a solution using base R that generates a transpose of your solution. That is, it creates a one-hot column vector for each individual character and concatenates these columns (i.e. there are always four rows, regardless of the number of strings).

(For a solution that produces the same format as the question, see the bottom.)

```r
sequences = c('ACTTTA', 'TTGATG', 'GATTACA')
```

```r
strsplit(sequences, '') |>
  lapply(match, table = c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    m = diag(0L, nrow = 4L, ncol = length(x))
    m[cbind(x, seq_along(x))] = 1L
    m
  }) |>
  do.call('cbind', args = _)
```

Or, alternatively (shorter but not necessarily more readable):

```r
strsplit(sequences, '') |>
  lapply(match, table = c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')) |>
  unlist() %>%
  {diag(1L, 4L)[, .]}
```

Unfortunately this requires the ‘magrittr’ pipe but we can change this (and make it more readable again) by abstracting the expression on the last line into a function:

```r
num_to_one_hot = function (x, bits) {
  diag(1L, bits)[, x]
}
```

This is a nice, general function to one-hot encode a numeric vector. Furthermore, we can `unlist` after the first step, which allows us to avoid `lapply`. And with that our DNA encoding code becomes:

```r
strsplit(sequences, '') |>
  unlist() |>
  match(c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')) |>
  num_to_one_hot(bits = 4L)
```

… which I find by far the most self-explanatory (and most readable!) of all the alternatives. It’s also fully vectorised, and doesn’t use `lapply` or similar, so it’s also more efficient.

---

For completeness, here’s a solution that produces the same output as requested in the question, by transforming the matrix produced by the previous algorithm from col-major to row-major orientation:

```r
strsplit(sequences, '') |>
  unlist() |>
  match(c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')) |>
  num_to_one_hot(4L) |>
  matrix(nrow = length(sequences), byrow = TRUE)
```

I benchmarked all currently posted solutions, and the ones using `num_to_one_hot` (`Konrad2` and `Konrad3` below) are the fastest:

```r
> bench::mark(Maël(), Paul(), Konrad1(), Konrad2(), Konrad3(), GKi1(), GKi2(), Thomas(), check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 8 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time       gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>     <list>  
# 1 Maël()        776µs 818.25µs     1154.    1.36KB    13.3    522     6    452.2ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 Paul()       1.07ms   1.17ms      743.    4.38KB     2.04   365     1    491.2ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 3 Konrad1()    21.7µs   23.7µs    39401.      432B    15.8   9996     4    253.7ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 4 Konrad2()     4.8µs    5.7µs   148619.    1.69KB    14.9   9999     1     67.3ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 5 Konrad3()     6.6µs    7.9µs   108540.    2.11KB    10.9   9999     1     92.1ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 6 GKi1()        9.2µs   10.8µs    83596.      960B    16.7   9998     2    119.6ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 7 GKi2()      258.3µs    278µs     3442.      960B     0     1721     0      500ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 8 Thomas()       10µs   11.6µs    77604.    2.39KB     7.76  9999     1    128.8ms <NULL> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can do:

```r
dna <- c("A", "C", "G", "T")
dna_seq <- c("ACTTTA", "TTGATG")

one_hot_encode <- function(x){
  spl <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  fa <- factor(spl, levels = dna)
  sapply(fa, table) |>
    Reduce(f = c, x = _)
}

data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(dna_seq, one_hot_encode)))
```

output

```r
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24
1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another *base* way.

```
s <- c("ACTTTA", "TTGATG", "CTTACG", "GTACGT")

dna <- c("A", "C", "G", "T")
lup <- setNames(asplit(diag(length(dna)), 1), dna)
lapply(strsplit(s, "", TRUE), \(x) unlist(lup[x], FALSE, FALSE))
#[[1]]
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
#
#[[3]]
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
#
#[[4]]
# [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Or using `gsub`

```
. <- gsub("A", "1000", s)
. <- gsub("C", "0100", .)
. <- gsub("G", "0010", .)
. <- gsub("T", "0001", .)
cbind(s, .)
#     s        .                         
#[1,] "ACTTTA" "100001000001000100011000"
#[2,] "TTGATG" "000100010010100000010010"
#[3,] "CTTACG" "010000010001100001000010"
#[4,] "GTACGT" "001000011000010000100001"

lapply(strsplit(., "", TRUE), as.integer)
#[[1]]
# [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
#
#[[3]]
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
#
#[[4]]
# [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

Or

```
lapply(strsplit(s, "", TRUE), \(x) c(diag(length(dna))[,match(x, dna)]))
```

Or

```
matrix(diag(4)[,unlist(lapply(strsplit(s, "", TRUE), match, dna), FALSE, FALSE)], length(s), byrow = TRUE)
```

Or

```
. <- chartr("ACGT", "1-4", s)
. <- strsplit(., "", TRUE)
matrix(diag(4)[, as.integer(unlist(.))], length(s), byrow = TRUE)
```

Or

```
. <- paste(s, collapse="")
. <- chartr("ACGT", "1-4", .)
matrix(diag(1L, 4L)[, utf8ToInt(.) - utf8ToInt("0")], length(s), byrow = TRUE)
```

Or

```
matrix(diag(1L, 4L)[,rep(1:4, utf8ToInt("ACGT") - 64)[utf8ToInt(paste(s, collapse="")) - 64]], length(s), byrow = TRUE)
```

---

Benchmark

```
library(magrittr) #For Konrad
s <- c("ACTTTA", "TTGATG", "CTTACG", "GTACGT")
dna <- c("A", "C", "G", "T")

bench::mark(check=FALSE,
            GKi1 = {lup <- setNames(asplit(diag(length(dna)), 1), dna)
              lapply(strsplit(s, "", TRUE), \(x) unlist(lup[x], FALSE, FALSE))},
GKi2 = {. <- gsub("A", "1000", s, fixed=TRUE)
  . <- gsub("C", "0100", ., fixed=TRUE)
  . <- gsub("G", "0010", ., fixed=TRUE)
  gsub("T", "0001", ., fixed=TRUE)},
GKi3 = lapply(strsplit(s, "", TRUE), \(x) c(diag(length(dna))[,match(x, dna)])),
GKi4 = matrix(diag(4)[,unlist(lapply(strsplit(s, "", TRUE), match, dna), FALSE, FALSE)], length(s), byrow = TRUE),
GKi5 = matrix(diag(4)[, as.integer(unlist(strsplit(chartr("ACGT", "1-4", s), "", TRUE)))], length(s), byrow = TRUE),
GKi6 = matrix(diag(1L, 4L)[, utf8ToInt(chartr("ACGT", "1-4", paste(s, collapse=""))) - utf8ToInt("0")], length(s), byrow = TRUE),
GKi7 = matrix(diag(1L, 4L)[,rep(1:4, utf8ToInt("ACGT") - 64)[utf8ToInt(paste(s, collapse="")) - 64]], length(s), byrow = TRUE),
Konrad = {
strsplit(s, '') |>
  lapply(match, table = c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T')) |>
  unlist() %>%
  {replace(diag(0L, 4L, length(.)), cbind(., seq_along(.)), 1L)}
},
Thomas = matrix(t(diag(4)[match(unlist(lapply(s, utf8ToInt)), utf8ToInt("ACGT")), ]), nrow = length(dna), byrow = TRUE)
         )
```

Result

```
  expression     min  median itr/s…¹ mem_al…² gc/se…³ n_itr  n_gc total…⁴ result
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:by>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>
1 GKi1          23µs 26.31µs  33203.   3.96MB    69.9  9979    21 300.5ms <NULL>
2 GKi2        6.97µs  8.27µs 109392.       0B    98.5  9991     9  91.3ms <NULL>
3 GKi3       12.39µs 15.41µs  51404. 169.84KB    87.5  9983    17 194.2ms <NULL>
4 GKi4        8.21µs 10.67µs  80760.   1.59KB   121.   9985    15 123.6ms <NULL>
5 GKi5        7.03µs  8.43µs 108751.    6.2KB    76.2  9993     7  91.9ms <NULL>
6 GKi6         6.2µs  7.62µs 118818.     864B    95.1  9992     8  84.1ms <NULL>
7 GKi7        5.64µs  7.46µs 113596.   1.08KB    90.9  9992     8    88ms <NULL>
8 Konrad     11.18µs 13.91µs  60428.   8.92KB   103.   9983    17 165.2ms <NULL>
9 Thomas       8.4µs 10.75µs  77019.   6.34KB    69.4  9991     9 129.7ms <NULL>
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `match` and `utf8ToInt` to find the mapping position, and `matrix` to format the output, e.g.,

```
dna <- c("ACTTTA", "TTGATG", "CTTACG", "GTACGT")
matrix(t(diag(4)[match(unlist(lapply(dna, utf8ToInt)), utf8ToInt("ACGT")), ]), nrow = length(dna), byrow = TRUE)
```

such that we will obtain

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0     0     0     1     0     0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0     0     1     0     1     0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     1     1     0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     0     0     0     0     1
     [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24]
[1,]     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0
[3,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
[4,]     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Note, base order is wanted as `ACGT` I think (not `ACTG`), based on OPs example.  That would just be a tweak to the second `utf8ToInt()`, right?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen yes, you are right, You just need to replace with "ACGT". Sorry for the typo. Please see my correction.